# R sparkline and markdown <!–/html_preserve–> error

Tags: html, r, charts, markdown

I'm trying to put sparkline charts: https://github.com/htmlwidgets/sparkline to markdown and make html file. It works when I kint it from html, but when I do this from terminal:
`knitr::knit2html('new_Rmd_file.Rmd')`

insted of sparkline charts in html file I see:
`<!–html_preserve–>`

any thoughts?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of the .Rmd.  I'll be happy to help but this doesn't give me much.  You can try `rmarkdown::render` to see if that produces a better result.

Comment: `rmarkdown::render` solved the problen! Thanks!